# Add [Is Primary Key Column] to this query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, metadata

I made this query, to list tables, its columns, data type and etc:

```
select t.name as 'Table',
       c.name 'Column',
       ty.name 'Data_Type',
       c.max_length as 'Max_Lenght',
       c.is_nullable as 'Null',
       c.is_identity as 'Identity'
from sys.tables t
    join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id
    join sys.types ty on c.system_type_id=ty.system_type_id
        order by 1
```

I have 2 questions:

**Ques.1:**

How can I add a column `'Is primary key?'` to it? I could not find a table that help me ( I took a look at `sys.indexes`, `sys.foreign_keys`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table_constraints` ).

**Ques.2:**

In `sys.columns`, int values have the `max_lenght` as 4, and some other fields too. What is this 4? 4kb per data? `datetime` and `decimal` too.

Thanks.

Comment: Also primary keys are not always a single column. They are often composite, made from 2 or more columns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Query that adds "is_primary_key" field for each column**

The `sys.key_constraints` and `sys.index_columns` catalog views will identify the PK columns. You can JOIN them together and then use that set as a derived table to LEFT JOIN to your main query which will allow for not filtering out columns that are not part of a PK.

Also, you want to use `[user_type_id]` instead of `[system_type_id]` to avoid a Cartesian product. Most of the time there won't be a difference between these two fields. But if you have User Defined Data Types (UDDTs), or use the `sysname` datatype (which is an alias to `NVARCHAR(128)`), then the `[system_type_id]` value will be repeated in the `sys.types` catalog view.

The following query lists all fields in all tables, adding a computed field to denote if the column is part of the PK or not. It handles composite PKs as well.

```
SELECT tbl.[name] AS [TableName],
       col.[name] AS [ColumnName],
       ty.[name] AS [DataType],
       col.[max_length] AS [MaxLength],
       col.[is_nullable] AS [Nullable],
       col.[is_identity] AS [Identity],
       CONVERT(BIT, IIF(pkcol.index_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS [PrimaryKey]
FROM       sys.tables tbl
INNER JOIN sys.columns col
        ON col.[object_id] = tbl.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.types ty
        ON ty.[user_type_id] = col.[user_type_id] -- do not use system_type_id
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT ind.[object_id] AS [table_object_id], ind.[index_id], ind.[column_id]
           FROM   sys.index_columns ind
           INNER JOIN sys.key_constraints pks
                   ON pks.[parent_object_id] = ind.[object_id]
                  AND pks.[unique_index_id] = ind.[index_id]
           WHERE  pks.[type] = 'PK'
          ) pkcol
       ON pkcol.[table_object_id] = tbl.[object_id]
      AND pkcol.[column_id] = col.[column_id]
ORDER BY tbl.[name], col.[name];
```

**Info on `max_length` column**

The `max_length` column in `sys.columns` is the maximum number of *bytes* that the column can take up per row. In the case of fixed-length fields such as `INT`, `DATETIME`, etc, those fields always take up their maximum amount of space, unless you are using the `SPARSE` option (per column setting) or have enabled Data Compression (per index setting).

For variable-length fields such as `VARCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, `XML`, etc, that value is the maximum number of bytes it can take up. A value of `-1` indicates a value of approx 2 GB (`Int32.MaxValue`) which is used by the `MAX` (`VARCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, and `VARBINARY`) and `XML` types.

The Unicode string types (`NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR`) that are not declared as `MAX` will display a `max_length` of `2 * declared_max` since the (safe) assumption is that they use 2 bytes per "character". This is not *always* the case since Supplementary Characters are actually 4 bytes per "character". But, this is why `sysname`, being an alias for `NVARCHAR(128)`, has a `max_length` of 256. Similarly, the less frequently used Double Byte Character Set (DBCS) collations that allow for mapping more than 256 characters in an 8-bit `VARCHAR` / `CHAR` field will store characters in either 1 or 2 bytes, depending on the character. Meaning, for `VARCHAR` data using a DBCS collation, and for `NVARCHAR` data, declaring a column or variable as `VARCHAR(x)` or `NVARCHAR(x)` does not guarantee **x** characters are storable: you can only fit **x** characters if all of those characters are of the standard length for that type (i.e. 1 byte for `VARCHAR`, 2 bytes for `NVARCHAR`). So, an `NVARCHAR(3)` field is given 6 bytes maximum to use. That can fit: 3 regular two-bytes Unicode characters, or 1 regular two-byte character and 1 Supplementary Character at 4 bytes (which is only 2 characters, not 3). It cannot fit 2 Supplementary Characters as that would require 8 bytes.

The deprecated `TEXT`, `NTEXT`, and `IMAGE` types that nobody is using anymore (that's sarcasm) show a `max_length` of 16, presumably being the size of the pointer left on the data page that points to the LOB page holding the data.

Comment: Wow. this is what I need. thank you very much. It was more complicated than I tought. and it list the same number of rows as my query. Thanks

Comment: epic. Thank you. I love when I ask something simple, and I end up learning a lot more hahaha.

Answer (score 4):

**Ques.1:** First remember that primary keys are not always clustered keys which is what I think you really want.  However the answer is pretty much the same either way.  You need to look at `sys.indexes` to see the `is_primary` column.  This will tell you that the index is they primary key.  Then you need to look at `sys.index_columns` to see the actual columns in the index.

```
SELECT object_name(c.object_id) as Table_Name,
    c.name AS Column_Name,
    ty.name AS Data_Type,
    c.max_length AS Max_Length,
    c.is_nullable AS Nullability,
    c.is_identity AS Is_Identity,
    CASE WHEN PrimaryCols.column_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Is_Primary_Key
FROM sys.columns c
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ic.object_id, ic.column_id
    FROM sys.indexes ix
    JOIN sys.index_columns ic
        ON ix.object_id = ic.object_id
        AND ix.index_id = ic.index_id 
    WHERE is_primary_key = 1) PrimaryCols
    ON PrimaryCols.object_id = c.object_id
    AND PrimaryCols.column_id = c.column_id
JOIN sys.types ty
    ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
```

**Ques.2** That number is the precision.  Or the maximum number of bytes taken up by the field (this column for one row).  In most cases maximum=actual but in a few (varchar, nvarchar) the actual is number of characters + 2 and maximum is what you put + 2.  In the case of nchar & nvarchar each character actually takes up two bytes.

Comment: Hey @Kenneth thanks for your answer. I was trying to do something like this, but when I use your query, not all fields os some tables is listed. I will try to fix this andI will accept your answer If I can.

Comment: Sorry, just realized it's only pulling indexed columns (and might be pulling them twice) let me fix it real fast.